# Python Selenium Firefox <input type="date" /> select with .click()

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver

I know there are lots of these out there, but none has proved helpful yet. I cannot find the popup calendar no matter how hard I try. Any suggestions?

html:

```
<label for="id_start_date">Start Date</label>
  <input class="form-control" id="id_start_date" type="date" value="" />
```

test file:

```
    start_date = self.browser.find_element_by_id('id_start_date')

    start_date_label = self.browser.find_element_by_xpath(
        "//label[@for='id_start_date']"
    )
    self.assertEqual('Start Date', start_date_label.text)

    # Today's Date is preloaded into the field. Jeff clicks on it
    # and it pops open a little calender to choose a date.

    start_date.click()
    """
    What is supposed to go here so I can find and select my desired date?
    """
```

It does show up on my page when I manually check it. I am at a complete loss.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to click on the calendar. you can set the value because it is of the type "input".
Pay attention to the format of date, assuming that it is in the format (MM/dd/yyyy) the code below works.

```
start_date = self.browser.find_element_by_id('id_start_date')
start_date.clear() # clear any value that was in the field before (if you don't clear, will append the new string sent.)
start_date.send_keys("08/17/2018")
```

Comment: but what if I wanted to click on them? @Lucas Hamaguchi

Comment: For anyone who seeks to click on the date input in future, that's not possible in the latest version of selenium. The calendar popup is a a native control so there is not way to select it using CSS selectors. Try to inspect it and you will see it cannot be inspected.